# Rank-Nullity of Linear Functional.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I read in a text that rank of linear functional is $1$ and Nullity=$n-1$ if we consider a nonzero $n$ dimensional vector space $V$ to some scalar field. But I can not visualize it.
I want to see a few examples of maybe $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ Field.
In my opinion,
$T:V\to \mathbb{R^{2}}$, then $T(v)=(x,y)$, why should the rank be $1$ here?

Comment: A linear functional is, by definition, a linear map of some vector space into its field. The example you give is not a linear functional.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user912011 , so, T(x,y)=(x+y,y+2x), is this correct?

Comment: **DEFINITION** Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. We say $f:V\rightarrow F$ is a linear functional on $V$ if $f$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: @rust32627 . You are defining the the map from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to itself. That is simply a linear transformation. A linear functional is a special kind of linear transformation where the image is in the field over which the vector space is defined. So $T(x,y)=69x$ would be a linear functional.

Comment: Also $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $n\geq 2$ is not a field . Think about it . Can you divide by vectors?. What does even $\frac{1}{(x,y)}$ mean?.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron,  got it maybe. So $T(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})=100x_{1}$ is linear functional and has rank $1$?

Comment: Also the map should not be to "any scalar field". It should be to the field over which $V$ is defined as a vector space. Remeber , a vector space is always accomapanied by the field over which it is defined.

Comment: @rust32627 . Yeah that would do. As you can see, $T((1,0,0,..0))=100$. And hence it has rank $1$.  Because given any scalar $c\in F$ . You can see that $T(\frac{c}{100}(1,0,0,..0))=c$. Thus the image is the entire space $F$

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron, I am kind of new to this. Another quick question, if $T(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n})=100$ is not linear functional as it doesnt follow the rules of linear transformation.

Comment: @rust32627 . $T(x_{1},..x_{n})$ is not $100$. it is $100x_{1}$. Now verify the linearity.

Comment: I am saying that if it was $100$, I couldnt get $T(v_{1}+v_{2})=T(v_{1})+T(v_{2})$ . I just want to clear up all my confusion. if it was $100x_{1}$, it does have linearity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134229/discussion-between-mr-gandalf-sauron-and-rust32627).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is a vector space over $F$ then , a linear map $T:V\to F$ is called a linear functional.  You need to view the $F$ in the right hand side as a vector space of $1$ dimension over $F$. That is $\{1\}$ generates the vector space $F$ over $F$.

If the map is non-zero. That is if $T(v)\neq 0$ for some $v\in V$. Then the rank of this map is $1$. as $T(v)$ spans the entire space $F$ over $F$.

From the rank-nullity theorem it then follows that $\dim(\ker(T))=n-1$.

In your example the image($\mathbb{R^{2}})$ is not a field .

An example of a linear functional would be i-th coordinate map.

$\pi_{i}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\pi_{i}(c_{1},c_{2},...,c_{n})=c_{i}$.

Or even for a finite dimensional vector space with basis($\{v_{1},v_{2},..v_{n}\}$) you can define like this:-

$f_{i}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}v_{i})=c_{i}$.

If you want from an infinite dimensional vector space, consider the evaluation map.

$ev_{a}:P(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $ev_{a}(f(x))=f(a)$. Where $P(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the space of real polynomials and $a\in\mathbb{R}$.